# How does IBM-850 encoding work with PHP function parameters?

Tags: php, character-encoding, obfuscation

In [this code golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111501), [aross](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38392/aross) gives a solution that presumably uses IBM-850 encoding as parameter values in PHP"

```
echo preg_filter("/^(.*?[aeiouy]+)/i","$1 $1 $0",$argn);
echo preg_filter(~ðíÎÐı└ñ×ÜûÉèåóÈÍðû,~█╬▀█╬▀█¤,$argn);     # Encoded
```

How does this work? Why are the parameters not quoted? How come only the parameters are encoded and not the rest of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It hasn't so much to do with [IBM-850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), that's just a codepage filling out the 8th bit beyond [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) to give a representation to the bytes you'll end up with.

The key here is the [bitwise *not* operator `~`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) which flips all the bits - 0 becomes 1, and 1 becomes 0. If you dump `~"/^(.*?[aeiouy]+)/i"` to a file and open it up as 850 it'll look like:

```
ðíÎÐı└ñ×ÜûÉèåóÈÍðû
```

And likewise `~"$1 $1 $0"` looks like:

```
█╬▀█╬▀█¤
```

So you see where this is headed.

In PHP an undefined constant is assumed to have a string value matching its name. For example:

```
var_dump(foo);
```

Outputs `string(3) "foo"` (as well as the notice *"Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo'"*, if notices are on.)

When either of the two gibberish strings above are put in a PHP script without quotes they're taken as undefined constants with their names assumed for their values as well.

Now prepend each with `~` to flip their bits back and you've got the original regex and replacement strings:

```
preg_filter("/^(.*?[aeiouy]+)/i","$1 $1 $0",$argn)
```

---

Only those parameters had their bits flipped because they're the only string literals, which is what this trick applies to. For each string it's shaving off a pair of quotes in exchange for taking on only a single tilde.

The bit flipping had to be done because either of the original strings on their own without quotes would've landed parse errors.

Clever way to net two bytes.